# node.js socket.io confusing "socket" under different namespace

Tags: node.js, socket.io

If I have both

```
var io = io.of('/')
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){ });
});
```

and

```
var nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){ });
});
```

Would there be any conflict when socket.on() is called inside of each name space?

Comment: Can you back up and describe what actual problem you're trying to solve?  What is it you want to accomplish from your client?  Each socket.io connection connects to one namespace, so if you want to connect to two separate namespaces, you can use two separate socket.io connections from the client (though that may not be the most efficient way to solve your actual problem).

Comment: I was readying the tutorial, just wondering, not really trying to accomplish anything at the moment. http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there won't be any conflict. When socket.on() is called in different namespace-d io connection, they are isolated from each other.
When connected from front-end, they are still separate connections.

Answer (score 0):

Both `socket.on` statements are talking to different `socket` objects.

The line

```
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
```

is providing you with a new object for every connection.